In next.js 13, How to use code in url param to exchange tokens with custom providers in next-auth?
So I have created a custom provider in next auth like this :
 {
  id: "oidc",
  name: "OIDC",
  type: "oauth",
  authorization: {
    url: "https://www.auth.mywebsite.com/oauth2/authorize",
    params: {
      scope: "openid email profile aws.cognito.signin.user.admin",
      response_type: "code",
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
      identity_provider: "Google-OIDC",
    },
  },
  idToken: true,
  checks: ["state"],
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,

},

It works as in user can sign in with this but I am not able to create a session object as all I get from this is that user gets redirected to home page with a code in url params and now I need to send this code to exchange tokens. But how do I do it here? For some reason this provider is not even reaching the callback
My callback :
session: { strategy: "jwt", maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, trigger, account, user, session }) {
      console.log("I am here, yes I am");

But it won't register this log while the providers as provided by next auth works fine, only my custom provider is not able to start this callback.
